# NodeJS with Contentful code does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb, contentful

I am using the below code to display content (of type "course"), but when I hit http://localhost:3000/api/courses, nothing happens the browser keeps rotating forever and there is no error messages on console either. The same request works fine in the POSTMAN by using GET method. My sincere request if some one can suggest what is wrong in my code.

1. POSTMAN GET Request, (For getting courses data from Contentful CMS); it works fine and returns courses JSON data.

   > cdn.contentful.com/spaces/9f3v4l5x639t/entries?access_token=l83Wr4f12LlnCfo71Jv4NwSyt2x-M1Q0AQ22O5kRuEI&content_type=course&include=2

---

---

2. Actual code which does not work by using http://localhost:3000/api/courses For getting courses data from Contentful CMS

   ```
   getCourses = async (req, res) => {
   const client = contentful.createClient({
       space: '9f3v4l5x639t',
       accessToken: 'l83Wr4f12LlnCfo71Jv4NwSyt2x-M1Q0AQ22O5kRuEI'
     });

     client.getEntries({
       content_type: 'course',
       locale: 'en-US',
       order: '-sys.createdAt', // Ordering the entries by creation date
       include: 2 // We use include param to increase the link level, the include value goes from 1 to 6

             },(err, courses) =>{
           if (err) {
               return res.status(400).json({ success: false, error: err })
           }
           if (!courses.length) {
               return res
                   .status(404)
                   .json({ success: false, error: `Movie not found` })
           }
           return res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: courses })
       }).catch(err => console.log(err))
   }
   ```
3. ROUTER CODE:

   ```
   router.get('/movies', MovieCtrl.getMovies)
   router.get('/courses', MovieCtrl.getCourses)
   ```
4. Request for Movies just works fine and displays JSON data: The only difference I am getting movies data from MongoDB is ==>http://localhost:3000/api/movies

Comment: You dont return anything on error(in catch block).  Also why you create the client for each request?

Comment: hi Seti, thanks for your suggestions, I have changed the code and created separate .js file for client. and also added return statement in the catch block. But still unable to get result

Comment: Are there errors shown?

Comment: Unfortunately, No errors shown either. It simply hangs in the browser

Answer (score 0):

client.getEntries is a asynchronous function try await before that maybe that gives the issue in this case

```
getCourses = async (req, res) => {
 const client = contentful.createClient({
 space: '9f3v4l5x639t',
 accessToken: 'l83Wr4f12LlnCfo71Jv4NwSyt2x-M1Q0AQ22O5kRuEI'
});

try {
const courses = await client.getEntries({
  content_type: 'course',
  locale: 'en-US',
  order: '-sys.createdAt',
  include: 2
});

if (!courses.items.length) {
  return res.status(404).json({ success: false, error: `Courses not 
 found` });
}

return res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: courses.items });
 } catch (err) {
console.error(err);
return res.status(500).json({ success: false, error: 'Server error' });
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mehul. As you suggested, I added await and seperated client code into cf.js. No luck yet! getCourses = async (req, res) => {
try{
    await  cf.api.getEntries({
        content_type: 'course',
        locale: 'en-US',
        limit: 5,
        order: '-sys.createdAt',  
        include: 2 // ORIGINAL CODE AS IT IS             return res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: courses })
            })}catch(err){
        console.log("In Catch Block")
        console.log(err)
        return res.status(404).json({ success: false, error: `Unable to connect`  })
        }
    }

Comment: The courses variable is not defined before being used in the response (data: courses). In your original code, you fetched the courses data from Contentful using the client.getEntries method. Since you are now using await cf.api.getEntries({...}), the result should be stored in a variable before sending the response.

Comment: hi Mehul, really sorry. Now I updated the code exactly like you suggested but something is still blocking it. I will update the modified code in my original question. Can you please check once.

Comment: getCourses = async (req, res) => {
  
try{ const courses = await cf.api.getEntries({
        content_type: 'course',
        locale: 'en-US',
        order: '-sys.createdAt', // Ordering the entries by creation date
        include: 1 //  },(err, courses) =>{
            if (err) {
                return res.status(400).json({ success: false, error: err })
            } return res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: courses.items[0] })
        })}catch(err){
        console.log("Catch Block")
        return res.status(404).json({ success: false, error: `Can't connect`  })
}